# Jquerymobile: toggle between 2 images as open panel icon not working

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile, mobile, panel

I tried to toggle between 2 images that it's open and close panel icon but not working, I had tried many ways but still not working.

Like below image,

1. The first load is open panel icon because the panel is closed.
2. the first clicked is work fine, panel opened and icon changed to close icon.
3. But the second clicked icon should change to open icon but it is still close icon, that's my problem. how to fix that?

```
<div class="ui-drawer">
        <a href="#myPanel"><img src="images/open.png" /></a>
        <a href="#myPanel"><img style="display:none;" src="images/close.png" /></a>
    </div>
```

```
 $(".ui-drawer").click(function(){
    $('img',this).toggle();
});
```

[image]

Comment: Create a similar demo here in a **Snippet** or in JSFiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working toggle for an image in a slideout. I had the same issue, as the image changed on first click, but on close it didn't toggle back. The work around was to bind the toggle to the `panelclose` event of the panel. Here is a working fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/M9QBb/396/ and code below. note that

```
 //first toggle
 $(".ui-drawer").click(function(){
    $(this).find('img').toggle();
 });
  //toggle back
 $( "#nav-panel" ).on( "panelclose", function( event, ui ) {
    $(".ui-drawer").find('img').toggle();
  } );
```